# Can we get messages from outlook grouped by conversations with REST API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, odata, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there any way to group response outlook messages by conversationId... like group through graph rest api's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, there's nothing in the API to do this grouping for you. Vote up this request: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/18765490-be-able-to-fetch-mails-by-conversations-in-folde

Comment: is there any api now?